# Where it is better to start a new thread for time consuming operations?

Tags: android

I'm wondering what is the best practice about initiation of new `threads` in Android or that is just a matter of taste. Shall I start `threads` for time consuming operations directly from the `Activity` or I need to delegate this to a separate class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndroidNoob,

Here is a good article on this from the Android Developers Blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

It looks like they create a new class for the `AsyncTask` and launch it from their UI Activity.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's mainly a question of reusability.

If your time consuming operation is only used by one class it's ok (in my opinion) to use a Thread.

If your operation will be used by more classes you should think about an AsyncTask.

Regards,
Tim